# Trying to expand/collapes jQuery Menu on DIV click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, I've done this before, but my code isn't working so I know I must be doing something wrong. I'm trying to expand my menu when visitors click on a div that contains a CSS generated image of either an Up arrow or a Down arrow. I don't want the sub-menu to open when the visitor clicks on the main link, because I still want that link to go somewhere. I can't get my code to co-operate. What am I doing wrong?

css is included in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lxcvpo4/).

**jQuery**

```
$("#b-links div").click(function(){

    //variables
    var mainMenu = $(this).closest("ul");
    var subMenu = $(this).siblings("ul");
    var openArrow = mainMenu.find("div.arrow-open");
    var openMenu = mainMenu.find("ul.open");

    //if this submenu is not currently open

    if (!$(this).is(openArrow)){

    openMenu.removeClass("open").slideUp(); //close open menu
    openArrow.removeClass("arrow-open").addClass("arrow-closed"); // change open arrow
    $(this).removeClass("arrow-closed").addClass("arrow-open"); // change closed arrow
    subMenu.addClass("open").slideDown(); // open this submenu

    } else {

    //if this submenu IS currently open

        openMenu.removeClass("open").slideUp(); close open menu
        openArrow.removeClass("arrow-open").addClass("arrow-closed"); change open arrow
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="b-links">
    <li><a href="#">Main Link</a><div class="arrow-closed"></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main Link</a><div class="arrow-closed"></div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Main Link</a><div class="arrow-closed"></div><ul>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu Link</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

The code actually does something in jsFiddle (the wrong thing, but at least something). The same code does nothing on my actual web page. And I have checked to make sure that jQuery does work on my page (I made a few things disappear).

Here is an image of my menu so you can see the arrows I'm talking about

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jquery this can be done as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#b-links ul').hide();  //  hide all ul elements which belongs to #b-link
    $('a').click(function(){  //  this works on link click. 
        $('#b-links ul').hide(); // hide displayed ul elements
        $(this).siblings().slideDown(); // show required element

    });
});
```

or on div click

```
$('#b-links div').click(function(){ 

    if($(this).hasClass('arrow-closed')){ 
        $('#b-links ul').slideUp();
        $('#b-links div').removeClass('arrow-open').addClass('arrow-closed');
        $(this).removeClass('arrow-closed').addClass('arrow-open');
        $(this).siblings().slideDown();
    }else{

        $(this).removeClass('arrow-open').addClass('arrow-closed');
        $('#b-links ul').slideUp();
    } 

});
```

And this is what is stopping jQuery from showing and hiding the elements

```
#b-links li ul li {
    display: none;
} 
#b-links li ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid. No wonder I couldn't see the list, I'd hidden it. Thank you so much for helping me with this!

Comment: One more question - why is there a space in-between my main LI's (the margin is set to 0px) and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: add this to css  ul  {
 padding-left: 0px;
}  it is default ul element  padding     or better    #b-links li ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

Comment: #b-links li { margin-left:- 4px;}